# Inactive Android SDK 'Install' button

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to install Android SDK through [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

As in the screenshot attached, even after Accepting the licenses, the 'install' button is still inactive? How do I check the dependencies and fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the "dependcies" section and the message just above and to the left of the cancel button indicate, you are missing the API 18 SDK package.

Install the Android API 18 SDK first, then try again.

Comment: In the previous screen, I'd already selected API 18 (screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/2M1Y3H2c1i2I). Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try installing that package first, then once it is installed attempt to install the system image again.